# Android - E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22 crash

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-animation, logcat

I needed some help in debugging my and finding out why my android application keeps on crashing. The app crashes on a page which has a listview and each listview row has an image and some text in it. I have created a cache class for storing all the bitmaps of the images in the listview. After about staying for an hour on that page(the page with the listview) the app crashes and this is what I see in the Logcat console. I cannot understand how this crash is happening, any tips or any suggestions on its root cause will extremely helpful. I apologize if the information is insufficient.

```
07-21 00:47:07.143    2047-2423/com.app E/Parcel﹕ Parcel::writeDupFileDescriptor failed:
    fd=931 flags=0 err=0(Success)
    dupFd=-1 dupErr=24(Too many open files) flags=-1 err=9(Bad file number)
07-21 00:47:07.172    2047-2423/com.app E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
07-21 00:47:07.172    2047-2423/com.app W/Adreno-EGLSUB﹕ <SwapBuffers:1344>: failed to queueBuffer
07-21 00:47:07.172    2047-2423/com.app W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3791>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
07-21 00:47:07.595    2047-2423/com.app E/Parcel﹕ Parcel::writeDupFileDescriptor failed:

. (the same error as above gets repeated a couple of times)
.
.

07-21 00:47:11.685    2047-2423/com.app W/Adreno-EGLSUB﹕ <SwapBuffers:1344>: failed to queueBuffer
07-21 00:47:11.685    2047-2423/com.app W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3791>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
07-21 00:47:12.128    2047-2423/com.app W/Adreno-GSL﹕ <gsl_ldd_control:416>: ioctl fd 28 code 0xc0140933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 24 Too many open files

. (the same error as above gets repeated a couple of times)
.
.

07-21 00:47:17.839    2047-2047/com.app W/InputMethodManager﹕ IME died: com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

I am also adding my xml layout if that is any helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:background="@color/black">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/visual_background_animation_list"/>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_holo_dark">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nxt"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nxt"

                android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
                android:id="@+id/curr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt"

                android:layout_below="@+id/seek_bar"
                android:id="@+id/curr_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_header">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/another_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/another_list_2"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I also wanted to mention that I have an animation-list which runs and is being displayed as background image of this application.

Layout of the navigation drawer

layout for navigation drawer

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name1"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name2"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And the layout of the listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="invisible">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_on_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_on_left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_title2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/another_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide code from getView method in list adapter?

Comment: @redsnowfox I added the layout of the navigation drawer I had and also of the listview

Comment: i just wanted to check whether you are populating the view properly or not. Specifically are you closing open file descriptors you are using or not.

Comment: When you say file descriptors, do you mean the images in the imageview?

Comment: As I am downloading those images in realtime and have an async task which does that. It does the images bitmaps and stores them in a cache

Comment: Please show the download async task and cache code, the error may be in there. Also as stated before, please supply your getView method.

Comment: If you are writing the download logic yourself then you might not be closing the inputstream.

Comment: can you let me know the number of item you are downloading from the server as I saw your logcat error it display the **TransactionTooLargeException** .

Comment: "fd=931 flags=0 err=0(Success)" <-- file descriptors shouldn't be that large -- looks like it's bumping up against the 1024 per-process limit. Very likely a file descriptor leak. `adb shell ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` will show you the list for a given process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on the net and in my code and found out that were many memory leaks. I changed a few things to get rid of that error.

1. I made sure that my context was not being cached in any of my helper classes (basically my utility classes)
2. Also I was not using a holder class in my listview

So I added the following declaration in my Custom Adapter class

```
  static class ViewHolder {
      TextView name;
      ImageView imageView;
  }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    ....
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}
```